# How to navigate through multiple nested divs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are using the following to navigate up through 4 html layers and then into the next div layer:

```
var inhalt = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next();
```

But how do we navigate into the first div sibling of our target layer? We have tried this, but this doesn't work:

```
var inhalt = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().next();
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:
Here's the HTML...

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="this is where we're starting from">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div id="this is where we need to get to">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first sibling is 3rd html layer ? or you mean first child ?

Comment: @Adrift. Thanks. Have posted the relevant HTML. We need to get one layer deeper than in the fiddle.

Comment: If you already have an id, then just use it like you normally would. There's no performance penalty imho compared to calling `.parent()` that many times.